# Rails Deploy Digitalocean ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano, digital-ocean

I'm deploying an app on digitalocean following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma#prerequisites

When I deploy with cap `cap production deploy:initial --trace` I keep getting this error

The deploy stops here: `01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01
      01 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::Inva…
      01`

and when I run bundle exec rake assets:precompile locally I get `yarn install v1.7.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.05s.`

I also installed yarn on the ubuntu server. I've made sure my ssh keys on the server are the same as my local ssh keys under ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and ~/.ssh/id_rsa

I was thinking it was an SSH issue, but I think it might be something else since I've thoroughly followed online guides on digitalocean and elsewhere.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This error was fixed by setting the secret keybase using export.

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="secret key"
```

To find or set your secret key in rails 5.2 use

```
rails credentials:edit
```

or if you haven't set your editor

```
EDITOR="vim --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

copy that secret key and then use the export line

Comment: Copy the secret key? Present in credentials.yml.enc? or master.key? @chrichar

Comment: rails credentials:edit generates a master.key already. It's just another way of using something similar to environment variables. What kind of error are you getting? The main takeaway if you're deploying on an ubuntu server is that it's probably an issue with your ssh keys. Make sure your local ssh keys in ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/ssh/id_rsa.pub match your server's ssh keys stored in the same location on your server. Also make sure you have added the id_rsa.pub keys to github